# Origin of "viking"

Tags: etymology

Is there any reason to discount a connection between "viking" and the Greek transliterated word "oikos"?
The Norse word shoes up in English words such as sandwich, and the Greek word goes back to a protoeuropean word relating to family and community.  On the surface, the Greek word seem to have a meaning that connects with that of the Norse word, but I have never seen this stated.  Usually, the Norse word is treated as relating to locality rather than community.  The Greek word does end up in English as -eco.

Comment: No, there’s no reason to discount such a connection. Indeed, according to the standard etymology as found on Wiktionary, for instance, the Old Norse word _vík_ ‘bay, inlet’ (whence _víkingr_ ‘someone from the bay’) **is** related to Greek οἶκος ‘home’. They both derive ultimately from the Proto-Indo-European root _*wei̯k̑-_ ‘settle(ment)’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That would be a good answer!

Comment: It's in Wikipedia.

Comment: A rather poetic take in critique of several etymologies is offered by William Sayers,
“Old Norse víking: Etymology, Semantics, Semiotics” in Journal of Indo-European Studies 2019